# python 3.x Keras ValueError: Error when checking target: expected seq_input to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (16, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am relatively new to Keras/Tensorflow so apologies if the question is basic.
I am trying to train a model on top of the VGG16 model.

## for VGG16 I am using:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), name='Image_input')
vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)
```

## then the model I want to train:

```
seq_model = Sequential(name='seq_input')
seq_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16.output_shape[1:],  name='flatten'))
seq_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', name='dense1'))
seq_model.add(Dense(62, activation='relu', name='dense2'))
seq_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
seq_model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='sigmoid', name='Output'))

seq_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## combine the two:

```
model = Model(input=vgg16.input, output=seq_model(vgg16.output))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## Data augmentation:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    classes=classes,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    classes=classes,
    class_mode='binary')
```

## fit

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

The code seems to break when I try to train the model; if i run them individually it seems to work, but when I combine them I get the error below (added full traceback in case it is useful)

```
Found 200 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 80 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nikfotei/Documents/Content/content/inHousemodel/trainModel.py", line 76, in <module>
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py353\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py353\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2077, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py353\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1791, in train_on_batch
    check_batch_axis=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py353\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1413, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py353\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 154, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected seq_input to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (16, 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?
Let me know in the comments if anything seems messy

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the shape of your labels in train and test?

Comment: @DvirSamuel I am using the flow_from_dir() method and it can recognise 2 classes so I guess [[0, 1]] sorry for not being clear on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your labels shape do not match the last layer output..
According to the code you published and according to the error it gives you, the shape of the labels are scalar(!) (0 or 1 probably) while the last layer of your model outputs array with shape 2 (something like ([0.1,0.9],[0.5,0.5] etc).
You should add to flow_from_directory function this param: class_mode="categorical"
 so your labels will be encoded to one-hot forma (0 will be [1,0] while 1 will be [0,1] for instance..)

Comment: thanks a lot! It was very confusing as the error seemed to be on the first layer, so I thought the issue was in the stitching of the two models!